# Backside color of CCTransitionPageTurn in Cocos2d-x 2.0

Tags: animation, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, transition

How can I specify the color of backside of a scene when I use CCTransitionPageTurn? In cocos2d-iphone 1.0, I did some modifications in blot() in CCGrid.m like this:

```
NSInteger n = gridSize_.x * gridSize_.y;
// Default GL states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_COLOR_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Needed states: GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY
    // Unneeded states: GL_COLOR_ARRAY
    //enable culling, the default cull face is back
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    //now only the front facing polygons are drawn
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoordinates);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
// This is very important, otherwise the backside of picture will be random color
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//change the winding of what OpenGl considers front facing
    //only the back facing polygons will be drawn
    //this works better then changing the cull face
    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glColor4ub(255,255,255,255);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indices);
//restore GL default states
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
```

This is cpp code, I think I can use in cocos2d-x. But unfortunately, this code doesn't work for 2.0. Can anybody suggest how to translate this to 2.0 ? Or is there alternative way to set color in backside of a scene during CCTransitionPageTurn?

Comment: But how? Can you advise in more details. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your snippet and other google searches I've managed to achieve this :

```
void CCGrid3D::blit(void)
{

    CCLOG("CCGrid3D::blit()");
    int n = m_sGridSize.width * m_sGridSize.height;

    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position | kCCVertexAttribFlag_TexCoords );
    m_pShaderProgram->use();
    m_pShaderProgram->setUniformsForBuiltins();;

    //
    // Attributes
    //
#ifdef EMSCRIPTEN
    // Size calculations from calculateVertexPoints().
    unsigned int numOfPoints = (m_sGridSize.width+1) * (m_sGridSize.height+1);

    // position
    setGLBufferData(m_pVertices, numOfPoints * sizeof(ccVertex3F), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    // texCoords
    setGLBufferData(m_pTexCoordinates, numOfPoints * sizeof(ccVertex2F), 1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    setGLIndexData(m_pIndices, n * 12, 0);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei) n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
#else

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, m_pVertices);
    glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_TexCoords, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, m_pTexCoordinates);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, m_pIndices);

    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, (GLsizei)n*6, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, m_pIndices);

    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

#endif // EMSCRIPTEN
    CC_INCREMENT_GL_DRAWS(1);
}
```

It has only one drawback : it does not let you specify the back color, but rather it gets the color of the bottom-left pixel and uses it. I hope this is enough for you, or that you will be able to change this so that it will let us specify the color needed.